# Rust From/Into traits not working as expected

Tags: rust, traits

I'm having some problems understanding the behavior of the Into trait. I'm playing with the example in chapter [6.1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) of "Rust by Example" and the behavior is not what I expected:

```
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Number {
    value: i32,
}

impl From<i32> for Number {
    fn from(item: i32) -> Self {
        Number { value: item }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let num = Number::from(30);
    println!("My number is {:?}", num);
    // println!("Why doesn't this work: {:?}", 5.into());
    println!("But this does: {:?}", <i32 as Into<Number>>::into(5));
    println!("So does this: {:?}", Into::<Number>::into(5));
}
```

I'm Having problems understanding why the commented line doesn't work, as the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) suggests that implementing From, automatically gives you a free implementation of Into, and it's using the same syntax as the other example in the page (see link above)

Additionally, I'm not sure how to make sense of the couple of lines below the commented line which do work.

Any pearls of wisdom?

Comment: `5.into()` could create a lot of different types, why would it pick `Number` over anything else? If you did `let num: Number = 5.into()` it would work.

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives us a hint at why it doesn't work:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:17:47
   |
17 |     println!("Why doesn't this work: {:?}", 5.into());
   |                                               ^^^^
   |
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
   |
17 |     println!("Why doesn't this work: {:?}", <i32 as Into<T>>::into(5));
   |                                             +++++++++++++++++++++++ ~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`
```

"`type annotations needed`" means the compiler cannot fill in the type `T` for the trait `Into<T>` in this context. Yes, `T` can be `Number`, but it could also be `i64`, and there is no way the compiler can guess which one you meant.

Using `.into()` by itself will work in a context where a `Number` is expected, however:

```rust
fn foo(number: Number) {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    foo(5.into());
}
```

In this case, the compiler can fill in `T` on the trait `Into<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Anders Evenson

Turns out that this also works:

```
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Number {
    value: i32,
}

impl From<i32> for Number {
    fn from(item: i32) -> Self {
        Number { value: item }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let num1: Number = 5.into();
    println!("My other number is {:?}", num);
}
```